# Getting Gradle 'my-application' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

Getting following error on android studio -

```
Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher
```

Studio suddenly crashed and after it when i am opening my project then getting above error. I am having 32 bit windows 7.

I have done following things -

1. Updated Android sdk (32 bit).
2. Changed path of sdk to our custom path.
3. Restarted computer as well.
4. Update java jdk to 1.8.0_112.

But still getting same error. Please suggest me where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `Android Studio`'s folder, you will find **2 programs**. One is for the **64bit** and one is for the **32bit**

Check which one you are using

[image]

Comment: I am using 32 bit. 64 bit is not being compatible with machine.

Comment: @AyushBhatnagar in AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, did you select the directory where the JDK is located?

Comment: yes before it was using default sdk path. and i have changed it also with my custom jdk directory.

Comment: @AyushBhatnagar try "invalidate cache and restart" on Android Studio

Comment: i have done all these things. but still facing same error.

Comment: @Ayush did you also unselect the "Use embedded jdk(recommended)" flag?

Comment: @Ayush last tip I can give you is looking [at this video](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjiwN-ZlIXRAhXJOhQKHSrFA_UQtwIIMjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D22pz5vnBEus&usg=AFQjCNH-SXN2_4kuVkLM8pa7arDQ2z_mKw&sig2=c3Ou6aFSEDuJ773g9FzkOQ&bvm=bv.142059868,d.d24)